# removing line feed from .style.display = "block";

Tags: html, styles, block

Using this HTML code, when I click the hide link, it hides the block but also adds a line feed.  How to eliminate the new/additional line feed?

Thank you.

```
function showTop1(){
    document.getElementById("top1opener").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("top1").style.display = "block";
}
function hideTop1(){
    document.getElementById("top1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("top1opener").style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"line feed" you mind that's element is block and stretching to 100% width?

```
<div id="top1opener" style="background-color:red;" onclick="showTop1()">
OPENER CONTENT
</div>

<div id="top1" style="background-color:green" onclick="hideTop1()">
TOP1 CONTENT
</div>

<script>
function showTop1() {
    document.getElementById("top1opener").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("top1").style.display = "inline";
}
function hideTop1() {
    document.getElementById("top1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("top1opener").style.display = "inline";
}
</script>
```

is that you means? elements in this code doesnt stretching to 100% width.

Comment: This one shows "hidetop1" and "showtop1".  I have a few of these (like hidetop2 etc). how to use one function setting to work with several show/hides?  Thank you.